# Copenhagen to Odense day trip

Tags: trains, day-trips, copenhagen

I will be spending time in Copenhagen and would like to take a day trip to Odense, specifically to see the Hans Christen Anderson attractions. Is train the best way to get there? Also, what stations would be the best to use?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Travel SE. Your question is subjective - what is for you the best way? The cheapest one? or the fastest one... or something else?